# Calling Ajax and returning response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have search for so many questions but didnt get the right answer.  I have made the following function from what my research i understand that ajax call is async so on its done passing a value to global variable and returning that but i get a blank or undefined value.i can do it with $('#someid').html in response or some other methods but i dont want to implement them . Any idea what i am doing wrong here

```
function SimpleAjax(form, postData, url)
{
    var returnData;
    var sendData;

    if (form == "") {
        sendData = postData;
    }
    else if (postData == "") {
        sendData = $(form).serialize();

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: sendData,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data != null || typeof data != 'undefined') {
                returnData = data;
            }
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        returnData = data;
    });

    return returnData;
}​
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so `returnData` won't be set until it's complete. Calling `SimpleAjax()` will always return undefined because the ajax request will not be completed before the function returns. Use callbacks.

Comment: You cannot return the response data because it is being retrieved asynchronously, as @jeremyharris just said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `return returnData;` happens before your success or done functions execute.  As you said, it's asynchronous.  However, your function SimpleAjax is running synchronously.

So it starts the Ajax call `$.ajax({ ... });`, then it executes the `return returnData;`.

What I do, is not use a global, that will just cause you headaches.  But pass in a function to execute on success, rather than trying to return the result.

Something like...

```
function SimpleAjax(form, postData, url, successCallback)
{
    var returnData;
    var sendData;

    if (form == "") {
        sendData = postData;
    }
    else if (postData == "") {
        sendData = $(form).serialize();

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: sendData,
        success: successCallback
    });
}​

//TODO: set your input parameters
SimpleAjax(form, postdata, url, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: @AbdulBasit, excellent, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer as well i thought that .done  will do the magic and will return value after ajax completes however it wasnt doing ....
just put this code
    async: false,

in ajax and it will work

```
   function SimpleAjax(form,postData,url)

    {

    var returnData;
   var sendData;
 if (form == "")
  {
    sendData=postData;  
  }
  else if(postData=="")
  {
    sendData=$(form).serialize();     

  }





        $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    data:sendData ,
   async: false, 
    success: function(data)                

    {
    if (data != null || typeof data!='undefined')   
    {  
    returnData= data;


    }

    } 



    });


    return returnData;


      }
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea.  Not making async callbacks will cause you a lot of grief.  It slows down your pages, and negates all the advantages of using Ajax.

Comment: Just note that asynchronous AJAX is strongly discouraged. It presents many disadvantages, and deviates from the common programming patterns of Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Following the other answer thru call back